# Not getting expected result - string concatenation

Tags: c++, g++, linux-mint

I have written(copied and modified) a code with an objective to concatenate all the lines into a single string in a file. However i am getting unexpected result.

```
//Fillvector.cpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");
    string line;
    string finalString="";
    while(getline(in, line))
    v.push_back(line);
    for(int i=0; i < (int)v.size(); i++) {
    finalString += v[i];
    }
    cout << finalString << endl;
}
```

The result which I am getting on my terminal is

```
}nt maincout << finalString << endl;(); i++) {
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Indenting your code will greatly help you to learn what is going on with things, not to mention having others look at it...

Comment: This doesn't stop your code from compiling, but if you run with `-Wall` you'll see a warning for a comparison between unsigned and sign int in your for-loop conditional. You can fix that by declaring `i` as an unsigned int, or by casting the result of `v.size()` to int. This is explained in a better format here: http://cplusplus.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Warning:_comparison_between_signed_and_unsigned_integer_expressions

Comment: Looks like all of you are getting it except me. Dont know whats wrong.

Comment: @AdamBernier Looks like it should be some problem with my system as all others are able to get it right. But I dont know what problem it is and how to rectify it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `endl` character is just a `CR` without a following `LF`.  That means each additional line out output is written over the previous line, so what you'll see is the last character that was displayed in each column.

---

After a closer look, the problem is in the line

```
finalString += v[i];
```

which should be

```
finalString += v[i] + "\n";
```

Otherwise you're concatenating strings that end with `CR` (carriage return) characters, but no `LF` (linefeed, or new line) characters.

Comment: How is that supposed to abwer the question?

Comment: @eudoxos: Sorry, I was called away before I could complete my answer.  Better?

Comment: This would explain why you get the output you are getting. Your program actually prints all lines, but instead of printing each line on a new line, your program goes to the beginning of the line (using a CR -- or Carriage Return) and prints the new text ON TOP of the old output. For example the `}` at the beginning comes from the one on the last line. the `nt` comes from the `int` in `int main`-line, etc.

Comment: @Lindydancer the explanation seems correct but how to make it work fine ?

Comment: @Lindydancer does that mean that I need to replace carriage return with some other character?

Comment: Updated the answer with a better explanation and solution.

Comment: @AdamLiss But doing so will print my code in multiple lines. I want to print it all in a single line as what others are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. works for me (MinGW G++ 4.6.1, Windows):

```
C:\>fillvector
//Fillvector.cpp#include <string>#include <iostream>#include <fstream>#include <
vector>using namespace std;int main() {vector<string> v;ifstream in("Fillvector.
cpp");string line;string finalString;while(getline(in, line))v.push_back(line);f
or(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {finalString += v[i];}cout << finalString << endl
;}

C:\>
```

So, what compiler and OS are you using?

Also, note that `getline` removes the linebreaks, so you might want to change the code slightly:

```
[...]
while(getline(in, line)) {
  v.push_back(line);
  v.push_back("\n");
}
[...]
```

After that change, your code will behave quite similar to `cat fillvector.cpp` or `type fillvector.cpp`.

Comment: i am using g++ compiler and linux mint 11 OS.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code has no problem.**

```
$ g++ Fillvector.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
//Fillvector.cpp#include <string>#include <iostream>#include <fstream>#include <vector>using namespace std;int main(){    vector < string > v;    ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");    string line;    string finalString;    while (getline(in, line))        v.push_back(line);    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {        finalString += v[i];    }    cout << finalString << endl;}
$ ./a.out  | wc -l
1
```

See the log above. The last line counts the number of line. and its **1**.

Comment: even for me its giving 1. But its not printing the string correctly. Any command to see number of words ?

Comment: `$ ./a.out | wc -w` to get # of words. Alternatively `./a.out | wc -c` will give you # of bytes. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix) .  But the default display of `wc` -- at least on my machine -- is to show <tab>lines<tab>words<tab>bytes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getline()` [includes the terminating newline character](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), which you want to remove or replace with a space.  See [Im getting a lineshift when trying to build a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635321/im-getting-a-lineshift-when-trying-to-build-a-string/9635544#9635544) for the answer to a similar question.

Comment: How come its working for others if not for me ? This is one of the code which comes along with "Thinking in C++". I wonder how others did if I could not